# How can I get ctags to generate tags for functions with dashes in bash?

Tags: bash, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Some functions in bash have hyphens or dashes, like:

```
function detect-project {
    ...
}
```

But Exuberant Ctags 5.8 only creates a reference for the tag `detect`. From the generated `tags` file:

```
detect  util.sh /^function detect-project () {$/;"  f
```

How can I get it to generate a tag for `detect-project`?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/fishman/ctags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hyphens (or other special characters with the exception of underscores) is not recommended in bash, and leads to much confusion, as in this case.  Best bet is to rename them!

Having said that, your other option is to add a custom `bash` language definition to ctags.  You could simply copy the one that is used by default (sh.c in the source) and modify it.  The relevant section to replace:

```
    while (isalnum ((int) *cp)  ||  *cp == '_')
    {
        vStringPut (name, (int) *cp);
        ++cp;
    }
```

becomes

```
    while (isalnum ((int) *cp)  ||  *cp == '_' || *cp == '-')
    {
        vStringPut (name, (int) *cp);
        ++cp;
    }
```

I haven't tested that, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) can capture whole the name without any extra configuration.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat foo.sh
function detect-project {
    ...
}
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -o - ./foo.sh
detect-project  ./foo.sh    /^function detect-project {$/;" f
```